# How to share an image and video from an iPhone application to facebook using FBSDKShareKit

Tags: ios8

I am new to ios development,how to share images and videos from iphne application to facebook using FBSDKShareKit.

```
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.JPG"];
    photo.userGenerated = YES;
    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[[FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:photo.image userGenerated:YES] ];
    //content.photos = @[photo];

    // Assuming self implements <FBSDKSharingDelegate>
    [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];
```

can any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more details. Do you get errors?

Comment: i need some example to share images on fb